# bcp error: conversion/operation resulted in overflow

Tags: sql, sybase, bcp

I have a text file with 8-digit numbers that I want to copy into a Sybase table that I created as:

create table foo ( id numeric(20) )

I'm using numeric so I can join with another numeric column in an existing table.

The format information from my bcp command is:
10.0
1
1       SYBNUMERIC      1       12      "\n"    1       id 20      0

The bcp copy fails with the following message repeated several times:

CSLIB Message:  - L0/O0/S0/N20/1/0:
cs_convert: cslib user api layer: common library error: The conversion/operation resulted in overflow.

I don't see any numbers that could cause an overflow in my input text file.

Any suggestion on how I might copy this data and/or why this is failing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered my table for id to be int.  bcp did not error out but the data was incorrect.

So I altered the table for id as a varchar and bcp worked fine.  Then I altered the id back to numeric(20) and it works.

This does not solve the bcp question but did give me a solution to get at the data I need which is the real goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the -c parameter without -f. It will not prompt for format and it will work properly. the problem is usually the incorrect default values that format is using.